# videoview in android application is totaly blank

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

i'm having problem with Videoview. i have done all the settings right but still it dosen't show anything in Videoview. finally i used a library but the problem was'nt solved. i used the videoview inside the recyclerview like the example in github: (https://github.com/Krupen/AutoplayVideos), here is my code, and single_view is the layout for each item:
single_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:bvp="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/lay_parent_parentView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/parent_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_TD_padding_listItem"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_TD_padding_listItem"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/parent_margin"
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

<!--style="@style/CardViewStyle"-->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <com.allattentionhere.autoplayvideos.AAH_VideoImage
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"/>
```

this is my main layout which contains the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent_storyDet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >




        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.homaplus.hashtag.hashtag.Fragments.Frag_story_detail">


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                           <com.allattentionhere.autoplayvideos.AAH_CustomRecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/recycler_storyRelatedVideos"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


                        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The recyclerView Adapter:

```
public class MyVideosAdapter extends AAH_VideosAdapter {

    private List<String> list;


    public class MyViewHolder extends AAH_CustomViewHolder {


        //to mute/un-mute video (optional)
        boolean isMuted;

        public MyViewHolder(View x) {
            super(x);

        }
    }

    public MyVideosAdapter(List<String> list_urls) {
        this.list = list_urls;

    }

    @Override
    public AAH_CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_videos, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AAH_CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.setVideoUrl(list.get(position));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

finally i set the recyclerview in my fragment as folloe:

```
 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager2.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

        recycler_storyRelatedVideos.setActivity(getActivity());
        recycler_storyRelatedVideos.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager2);
        adapter_videos = new MyVideosAdapter(story.getList_storyVideos());

        recycler_storyRelatedVideos.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recycler_storyRelatedVideos.setAdapter(adapter_videos);
        recycler_storyRelatedVideos.smoothScrollBy(0,1);
        recycler_storyRelatedVideos.smoothScrollBy(0,-1);
```

Comment: the problem might be in `setVideoUrl` method, which you didn't show.

Comment: thanks for your comment. the "setVideoUrl " method is the method which has been defined in the library and i have used it just like the example in github,

Comment: @mary you got any solution ?